# How to check if two sprites has the same Texture Region - Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been searching for this various hours ago and I haven't got anything.

How I can check if two sprites has the same Texture Region?, is there a method or a way to do it?

I am using Libgdx

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I changed the method code to:

```
   public static boolean sameTextureRegions(Sprite sprite1, Sprite sprite2) {
    return sprite1.getTexture().equals(sprite2.getTexture()) &&
        sprite1.getOriginX() == sprite2.getOriginX()&&
        sprite1.getOriginY() == sprite2.getOriginY()&&
        sprite1.getRegionX() == sprite2.getRegionX()&&
        sprite1.getRegionY() == sprite2.getRegionY();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public static boolean sameTextureRegions(Sprite sprite1, Sprite sprite2) {
    return sprite1.getTexture().equals(sprite2.getTexture()) &&
        sprite1.getRegionX() == sprite2.getRegionX() &&
        sprite1.getRegionY() == sprite2.getRegionY() &&
        sprite1.getRegionWidth() == sprite2.getRegionWidth() &&
        sprite1.getRegionHeight() == sprite2.getRegionHeight();
}
```

Comment: You are checking twice for regionX and regionY which is redundant, and not checking for width if the regions. In some cases this would return false when is actually true. (but in wierd cases)